# Magento 2 - How to override knockoutjs template which is already overriden from a third party module?

Tags: magento2, theme, overrides, knockoutjs, template-override

I try to override the knockoutjs template `vendor\amasty\module-single-step-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\checkout\summary\item\details.html` from my own Theme.

The module `amasty\module-single-step-checkout` is registered as **Amasty_Checkout**

#### Attempt:

I copied the file into my theme at `THEME\Amasty_Checkout\web\template\checkout\summary\item\details.html` and made my changes, then I flushed the cache and the browser cache, but it still loads the old template.

I also executed `grunt clean` to clear static files. But it does not help either.